# How to add microsoft IME input language with batch file or cmd file

Tags: input, methods

I used the following code to add an input language with a batch file, but I can't find the secret code to add the Microsoft IME keyboard programmatically like the Japanese language.

Store in xml file:

```
<!--User List-->
<gs:UserList>
    <gs:User UserID="Current"/>
</gs:UserList>

<!--input preferences--> 
<gs:InputPreferences>
    <!--add pt-BR keyboard input and set as default-->
    <gs:InputLanguageID Action="add" ID="0416:00010416" Default="true"/>
</gs:InputPreferences>
```

Call from batch file:

```
control intl.cpl,, /f:"%CD%\pt.xml"
```

Comment: I know that I can use "0411:00010411" to add the Japanese input Language, but I need to know what ID to use for the Japanese Microsoft IME input Language for Windows 7.  Does anyone know what this is?